# Binding an ItemsControl to a collection using an Explicit UpdateSourceTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

**What I am trying to do**

I have a page with a number of fields on. The idea is that the user can edit the fields and then choose to either save or cancel. If save is chosen then the values should be persisted to the data source, if cancelled then the fields should revert to the original values.

For this I want to use `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` on my bindings.

**The part that works...**

Now this works if I have a simple TextBox, for example with:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb1" Text="{Binding Path=Model.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

the user can edit the text box as much as they want. Then if they save, I can persist with:

```
BindingExpression bindingExpression = tb1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
```

and I can revert the value with:

```
BindingExpression bindingExpression = tb1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
bindingExpression.UpdateTarget();
```

So far it all works great and I get the exact functionality I am looking for.

**The part that doesn't work...**

The problem I am having is that my pages also contains an `ItemsControl` which has a variable number of controls. This list binds to an `ObservableCollection<SomeClass>` on the data source.

Here is the XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Model.Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeValue}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The problem here is that the following code is not reverting the values in any of the listed items:

```
BindingExpression bindingExpression = ic1.GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty);
bindingExpression.UpdateTarget();
```

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the `TextBox` in the `DataTemplate` and somehow work with that instead?

Comment: I am not sure but isn't `ItemsControl` working on `ICollectionView`, have you tried that??

Comment: @XAMlMAX: Not sure what you mean. Have I tried what exactly?

Comment: Get the current view from your ItemsControl and refresh to reset.